# How do I configure emacs to bind something to meta-up?

Tags: emacs, configuration

This binds an operation to Control-p

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-p") (λ () (interactive) (previous-line 5)))
```

I would like to instead bind it to Meta-UpArrow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-<up>") (λ () (interactive) (previous-line 5)))
```

I figured this out by typing "C-h k" and then pressing meta + uparrow.

Comment: Hmmm. So that's what I did, and it didn't work - now I realized that's because it was already bound to something else. So I need to disable "paredit-splice-sexp-killing-backward". Just doing "(global-unset-key (kbd "M-<up>"))" doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Not sure I can help you there :-)

Comment: M-<up> may be bound locally instead of globally, in which case the local binding will shadow the global binding. So you may want to try local-unset-key and local-set-key.

Answer (score 0):

If use global set key, that mapping will be shadowed by a mode-specific mapping. So, while your mapping works in markdown-mode where there is no mode specific mapping for "M-<up>", it won't work in org-mode where  <M-up> maps to org-metaup.

So, if you really want to map "M-<up>" even if it may conflict with some modes that you use, you can do the following:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-<up>") (lambda () (interactive) (previous-line 5)))
(require 'org)
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "M-<up>") (lambda () (interactive) (previous-line 5)))
```

However, you need to do this (define-key) for every mode that you use that already has a mapping for  <M-up>.